# About deviceorientation event

Tags: javascript, html, web, frontend

Please use a mobile phone to run the demo of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation
I found a strange problem,
that is to say keep the phone horizontally (up the screen) first,
 for example, when I left tilting the phone, gamma close to -90 when continue to tilt, gamma will suddenly become 90 ,
the location of the ball will be a sudden from the side to the other side.
Why is this, and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [orientationchange](https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) from jquery.

Comment: Thank you,but I want to use DeviceOrientationEvent to control the movement of the element,just like the demo,please use a mobile phone to run demo of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Detecting_device_orientation

Comment: @noobPorting Detecting device orientation from mozilla no cross-browser.